# Writing multi-line strings into cells using openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm trying to write data into a cell, which has multiple line breaks (I believe \n), the resulting .xlsx has line breaks removed.
Is there a way to keep these line breaks?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: This won't work in recent versions of Openpyxl. See other answers.

In `openpyxl` you can set the `wrap_text` alignment property to wrap multi-line strings:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

workbook = Workbook()
worksheet = workbook.worksheets[0]
worksheet.title = "Sheet1"

worksheet.cell('A1').style.alignment.wrap_text = True
worksheet.cell('A1').value = "Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3"

workbook.save('wrap_text1.xlsx')
```

[image]

This is also possible with the [XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) module.

Here is a small working example:

```
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook

# Create an new Excel file and add a worksheet.
workbook = Workbook('wrap_text2.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Widen the first column to make the text clearer.
worksheet.set_column('A:A', 20)

# Add a cell format with text wrap on.
cell_format = workbook.add_format({'text_wrap': True})

# Write a wrapped string to a cell.
worksheet.write('A1', "Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3", cell_format)

workbook.close()
```

Comment: thanks for your help. Do you know by any chance a good documentation for python openpyxl with examples?

Comment: The latest OpenPyXL docs are [here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html). However, I figured out the syntax above by reading the code (and by having a general idea about what I was looking for). XlsxWriter has detailed [docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/contents.html) and [examples](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples.html).

Comment: I get duplication on both XlsxWriter and openpyxl modules. (E.g. - When I write "line1 \n line2" I get  "line1 \n line2 line1 \n line2 "

Comment: unresolved_external: The screenshot shows that the example generates the correct output. If you have a different or new issue start a new StackOverflow question with a small working example that demonstrates it.

Comment: I do this but the output in the cell is still just a single string with "\n" in it instead of a string split across multiple lines. Any idea why?

Comment: This answer is outdated. Won't work in recent versions. See other answer

Answer (score 80):

The API for styles changed for openpyxl >= 2. The following code demonstrates the modern API.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Alignment

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active # wb.active returns a Worksheet object
ws['A1'] = "Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3"
ws['A1'].alignment = Alignment(wrapText=True)
wb.save("wrap.xlsx")
```

Comment: Yes, the api has been changed and your code works correctly. Thank you!

Comment: For those who prefer snake case: `wrap_text` is also valid as per the [docs](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/openpyxl.styles.alignment.html#openpyxl.styles.alignment.Alignment.wrap_text)

Comment: The snake case stuff may be removed over time.

Answer (score 5):

Just an additional option, you can use text blocking """ my cell info here """ along with the text wrap Boolean in alignment and get the desired result as well.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Alignment

wb= Workbook()
sheet= wb.active
sheet.title = "Sheet1"

sheet['A1'] = """Line 1
Line 2
Line 3"""

sheet['A1'].alignment = Alignment(wrapText=True)

wb.save('wrap_text1.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 3):

Just in case anyone is looking for an example where we iterate over all cells to apply wrapping:

Small working example:

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Alignment
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows

# create a toy dataframe. Our goal is to replace commas (',') with line breaks and have Excel rendering \n as line breaks.
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[["Mark", "Student,26 y.o"],
                        ["Simon", "Student,31 y.o"]], 
                  columns=['Name', 'Description'])

# replace comma "," with '\n' in all cells
df = df.applymap(lambda v: v.replace(',', '\n') if isinstance(v, str) else v)

# Create an empty openpyxl Workbook. We will populate it by iteratively adding the dataframe's rows.
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active # to get the actual Worksheet object

# dataframe_to_rows allows to iterate over a dataframe with an interface
# compatible with openpyxl. Each df row will be added to the worksheet.
for r in dataframe_to_rows(df3, index=True, header=True):
    ws.append(r)

# iterate over each row and row's cells and apply text wrapping.
for row in ws:
  for cell in row:
    cell.alignment = Alignment(wrapText=True)

# export the workbook as an excel file.
wb.save("wrap.xlsx")
```