# Apply 'wrap_text' to all cells using openpyxl

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I have a Pandas dataframe that I am writing out to an XLSX using openpyxl. Many of the cells in the spreadsheet contain long sentences, and i want to set 'wrap_text' on all the contents of the sheet (i.e. every cell).

Is there a way to do this? I have seen openpyxl has an 'Alignment' option for 'wrap_text', but I cannot see how to apply this to all cells.

Edit:

Thanks to feedback, the following does the trick. Note - copy due to styles being immutable.

```
for row in ws.iter_rows():
    for cell in row:      
        cell.alignment =  cell.alignment.copy(wrapText=True)
```

Comment: You have to apply the format to every relevant cell.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Presumably, when you iterate through your cells, the idea would be to apply the format at that.

```
for row in ws.iter_rows():
    for cell in row:
        cell.style.alignment.wrap_text=True
```

There is also a fair amount more detail into how to use the wrap text style here
[Writing multi-line strings into cells using openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15370432/writing-multi-line-strings-into-cells-using-openpyxl])

Hope this helps.

Comment: When using indices to call cells, this should work:
`from openpyxl.styles import Alignment`
`_sheet.cell(1, 2).alignment = Alignment(wrapText=True)`

Answer (score 43):

I have been using openpyxl>=2.5.6. Let us say we want to wrap text for cell A1, then we can use the below code.

```
from openpyxl.styles import Alignment

ws['A1'].alignment = Alignment(wrap_text=True)
```

Answer (score 11):

```
import os
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import Alignment, Font
from openpyxl.cell import Cell
#format cells with word wrap and top alignment    
for row in ws2.iter_rows():  
    for cell in row:      
        cell.alignment = Alignment(wrap_text=True,vertical='top')
```

Answer (score 5):

## Update alignment in openpyxl v3

Many of the answers set `wrapText=True` but clobber existing alignment options. This is no good.

Using openpyxl v3.0.4, I did the following:

```py
import copy

for row in ws.iter_rows():
    for cell in row:      
        alignment = copy.copy(cell.alignment)
        alignment.wrapText=True
        cell.alignment = alignment
```

The original poster's solution uses:

```
cell.alignment =  cell.alignment.copy(wrapText=True)
```

But this produced the following warning:

```
DeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated function copy (Use copy(obj) or cell.obj = cell.obj + other).
  cell.alignment =  cell.alignment.copy(wrapText=True)
```

Answer (score -1):

Iterates all cells

```
  for rows in ws.iter_rows(min_row=1, min_col=1):
    for cell in rows:
      print('cell %s %s' % (cell.coordinate,cell.value))
```

*** Tested with Python:3.4.2 - openpyxl:2.4.1 ***