# Writing multi line SSH command output into a single Excel cell using xlsxwriter Module in Python

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

```
Below[enter image description here][1] is the abc.txt file output.

cat abc.txt
this is line1
this is line2
this is line3
```

Below is my program that connects to a remote server and executes a command, then writes the output into excel sheet.

The output appears in three cells.
I want the output in one cell.

Please help.

```
import paramiko
import xlsxwriter

try:
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('C:/users/S/Desktop/Example1.xlsx') 
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("MySheet") 
    cell_format = workbook.add_format({'text_wrap': True})
except:
    print("Could not create excel file")
else:
    row = 0
    col = 0
    cmds = ['cat abc.txt']

    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())


    ssh.connect('192.xxx.xx.xx', username='root', password = 'welcome')

    for cmd in cmds:
    # Execute the command on the 1st remote host.
        stdin, stdout,stderr  = ssh.exec_command(cmd)
        #print(cmd)
        for var in stdout:
            worksheet.write(row, col, var) 
            row += 1
print("Check for the excel file")
ssh.close()
workbook.close()
```

Regards.

Comment: You can give this a try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15370432/writing-multi-line-strings-into-cells-using-openpyxl

Comment: Hello Tim, Thanks for the response. 


I tried 

cell_format = workbook.add_format({'text_wrap': True})

worksheet.write(row, col, var, cell_format)

It is just wrapping the text and still giving three lines in three cells.

Comment: Any other ideas friends?

Comment: You would have to join the three lines with ‘\n’ and write them into one cell.

Comment: Hello Tim,

Tried this            worksheet.write(row, col + 1, var + ('\n'))

Still the same

Comment: worksheet.write(row, col, '\n'.join(var))   .. tried this as well.. still the same

Comment: have you tried worksheet.write(row,col,’\n’.join(stdout))? Is stdout a list?

Comment: Hi Tim, Yes I tried that

stdout is of type : <class 'paramiko.channel.ChannelFile'>

Comment: Hello Tim,

This worked>>>

stdin, stdout,stderr  = ssh.exec_command(cmd)
  #print(cmd)
  worksheet.write(row, col, '\n'.join(stdout), cell_format) 
  row += 1


Thanks a lot for your help..!! Really appreciate it!