# Combine Pandas df rows into one

Tags: python, pandas

For every two rows in my df, I would like to concatenate them into one.

Starting with this:

[image: Original]

and ending with this:

[image: desired]

I've been able to apply this to one column, but have not been able to apply it across all of them. I would also like to loop this for every two rows for the entire df.

This is my actual df:

```
                       Team         Spread 
0                Wagner Seahawks  (-11.5, -118)
1    Fairleigh Dickinson Knights   (11.5, -110)
```

I know this isn't the best way to format a table, but for my needs it is the best option. Thank you

If I were to do this in excel - I would use this:

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,A1:A2)
```

Comment: Can you please post actual sample dataframes, not images? I'm having a hard time imagining how the output is supposed to look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({
        "Col1": ["A", "B", "C", "D"],
        "Col2": [(-11.5, -118), (11.5, -110), (-11.5, -118), (11.5, -110)],
    })
>>> df
  Col1           Col2
0    A  (-11.5, -118)
1    B   (11.5, -110)
2    C  (-11.5, -118)
3    D   (11.5, -110)
```

If you have non-string columns, you'll need to transform them to string first:

```
>>> df["Col2"] = df["Col2"].astype(str)
```

Now, use `.groupby` using real floor division, and aggregate each pair of rows using `"\n".join`.

```
>>> df = df.groupby(df.index // 2).agg("\n".join)
>>> df
   Col1                         Col2
0  A\nB  (-11.5, -118)\n(11.5, -110)
1  C\nD  (-11.5, -118)\n(11.5, -110)
```

Consider that you would need to write the Excel file on your own to dump the dataframe and load the Excel in the format that you want (as described in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37651738/3281097)).

Comment: It's close, but it only leaves me with one column (the Team column)

Comment: @smitty_werben_jagerm now it should work with your non-string columns

Comment: perfect, nice catch there, thank you!